# HttpRequest Exception

Tags: asp.net

While calling Rest services(remote machine) from local machine i am getting httprequest exception,I found that this exception is coming while we are making    asynchronous call using httpclient in the code.

```
var httpresponse = await      _httpClient.SendAsync(httpClientRequests);
```

- Sometimes i am able to get response from services but it is happening **intermittently**.
- I have cross checked the request url also,it's correct.
- Also i am getting data only in debug mode not in release.
- Is this server side issue or client side?

Comment: put the full code to be able to help you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask